# 2000 Database and 2008 R2 SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

Can I query a 2000 database using a 2008 R2 SQL Management Studio, without having to upgrade the 2000 database to 2008?

My 2000 database is massive, so upgrading isn't an option.

Comment: just register the server and *i think* it's good to go.

Comment: Have you tried? Or are you trying to determine if you should install/upgrade SSMS?

Comment: BTW - How massive is the 2000 db? I assume it will continue to grow and at some point you will need to upgrade it - sooner the better... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe SSMS supports all versions of SQL Server from 2000 and up.